# Не выводит 1 значние с базы MySql

Tags: php

```
$link4 = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWORD);    
$query4 = "SELECT name, lastname FROM uchenik WHERE class='11' and bykva='Б'";

$result4 = mysql_query($query4, $link4);

$row4=mysql_fetch_array($result4)

?>
<p> Класс: 11 "Б"</p>
<p>Список учеников:</p>
<?

while($row4=mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
$uc = $row4["lastname"] ." ". $row4["name"];
print_r($uc);
}
```

Он выводит, если есть 3 записи 2 и 3, а 1 не выводит, как сделать? Т.е. есть 3 ученика: 11 класс Б он выведет только 2 и 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эту строчку, перед циклом, удалите:
$row4=mysql_fetch_array($result4)

Comment: Уже проблема решена, выше же написал. Все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Все, решил проблемы, надо было убрать кавычки с 11, во-первых, а во-вторых, я поставил

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

после

```
$result4 = mysql_query($query4, $link4);
```